# How to create set from list of sets in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, set, abaqus

In abaqus Python script, several Plies have a large number of copies, each of which has many fibers. In each Fiber, a set of edges has been selected: App1-1, App1-2, ..., App99-1, App99-2, ..., App99-88. How to create a new set that will contain all or some of these set of edges?
Thank you.

Code:

```
allApps=[]
...
for i in range(Plies):
    ...
    for j in range (Fiber):
        appSet = Model.rootAssembly.Set(edges=
            Model.rootAssembly.instances['Part'+str(i+1)+'-'+str(1+j)].edges[0:0+1], 
            name='App'+str(i+1)+'-'+str(1+j))
        allApps.append(appSet)
```

I can guess it should be something like this:

```
Model.rootAssembly.Set(name='allAppEdges', edges=.?.Array(allApps))
```

but I'm not sure about this and I have no idea about correct syntax

Comment: Have you looked at `part.EdgeArray`? I believe you'll have to `import part` explicitly, and you can create a new EdgeArray from a list of edges (`allApps` in your case): `...edges=part.EdgeArray(allApps))`

Comment: Do you want a simple union? Python set already supports that. Or "update". https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html  I would expect the same from this set, although I'm not entirely sure what library it is.

Comment: Thanks brady and Kenny Ostrom. Edges created in instances not in part. Example of appSet:
Model.rootAssembly.sets['App4-88'] and example of array allApps:
[Model.rootAssembly.sets['App1-1'], Model.rootAssembly.sets['App1-2'], ..., Model.rootAssembly.sets['App4-88']]

Comment: The `part` module just gives you access to the `EdgeArray` type. I don't think it matters that your edges are coming from an instance rather than a part. I'll write up an answer with an example that I think will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the following on a simple part and it worked for me. I think you could adapt this to achieve what you're trying to do for your specific model. The key is the `part.EdgeArray` type. For whatever reason Abaqus requires your edges be supplied within that type, rather than a simple list or tuple. The Abaqus documentation is not clear on this, and when you pass a list of edges it will fail with a vague error: `Feature creation failed`.

```
from abaqus import *
import part

mdl = mdb.models['Model-1']
inst = mdl.rootAssembly.instances['Part-1-1']

# Loop through all edges in the instance and add them to a list
my_edges = []
for e in inst.edges:
    my_edges.append(e)

# Create a new set with these edges
#mdl.rootAssembly.Set(name='my_edges', edges=my_edges) # This will fail because my_edges needs to be an EdgeArray
mdl.rootAssembly.Set(name='my_edges', edges=part.EdgeArray(my_edges))
```

For others that may find themselves here - similar types are available for vertices, faces, and cells: `part.VertexArray`, `part.FaceArray`, and `part.CellArray`.

Comment: Brady, thanks for the answer. Sorry, I didn't thank you earlier.